# Detect shape in a distorted image using opencv and python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working on a image processing project and I'm trying to detect the shape of a square in a distorted image with opencv 3.4.0 and python 3.

The image is this one:
[image: Input image]

As you can see the black square is pretty distorted, but I'm interested in detecting only the right side that will always be on focus and not distorted.

I've already tried to use the *Hough Line Transformation* method with the code below, but it detects the line right to the square:

```
temp = cv2.imread("images/macro/noF3.jpg")
grTemp = cv2.cvtColor(temp, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
asd = cv2.Canny(grTemp, 50, 150, apertureSize = 3)
lines = cv2.HoughLines(asd.copy(), 1, np.pi/180, 200)
for rho, theta in lines[0]:
    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)
    x0 = a*rho
    y0 = b*rho
    x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
    y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
    x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
    y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))

    cv2.line(temp, (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (255,0,0), 3)
```

[image: Hough Line Transformation]

I've also tried to use Canny and the findContours method, but it didn't work well, moreover I can't blur the image.
I would like to obtain the result seen in the image below:

[image: Desidered result]

Thanks

Comment: One trick is that even if you do blue the image to do the processing, you can always draw your results back onto the original image before you show.

Comment: you could try template matching: http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_template.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-features-detection-plot-template-py